# What is the P in LogP?

Tags: molecular-biology, protein-binding, medicinal-chemistry

How does this value actually get calculated?
Logarithms are usually written as
log(base 10) of x
So what is the 'P' equivalent of 'base 10'? I know it stands for octanol/water, but what does that actually mean in a computational context?

I've found many explanations of LogP online, but they usually just say the same thing, which is what LogP is used for. How does one actually calculate it?

Sorry if this is a ridiculously simple question. Bridging the gap between chemistry and math is not my strong suit.

Comment: If it's a bridge between Physics and Chemistry than either of those SE sites may be better than Bio.

Comment: If the base isn't specified it is usually assumed to be base 10. So you could write it as log10(P). see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_coefficient

Comment: Would be much easier to show a particular example.

Answer (score 0):

It means the following:

$$\log P = \log(P) = \log_{10}(P) = \log_{10} \left(\frac{C_{\mathrm{octanol}}}{C_{\mathrm{water}}} \right) $$

With $C_{\mathrm{octanol}}$ being the concentration of the solute in 1-octanol and $C_{\mathrm{water}}$ the concentration of the solute in water.

Comment: $C_\text{water}$ is not concentration of water but the concentration of the solute in water. Similarly for octanol.